# Best practices for deploying Unicorn Rails Apps (With Upstart)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I have a dedicated server running around 10 Rails apps using Nginx, Unicorn and Ruby 1.9.2 etc. I also use capistrano for deployment.

What I'm after, is some advice regarding a best practices for running and deploying these apps.

Each app has their own home directory and user account. However, at the moment I have them setup in the sudoers file so they can restart the app upon deployment (I have capistrano configured to run a restart.sh script). This means I have to type in the user's password upon deploying (capistrano prompts me when trying to run restart.sh).

Can upstart daemons be configured to run without sudo permissions?

Is there a better way to do this?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run the ROR applications as the user who is running the Capistrano deploy script, and have that user own (or have the permission to run) the restart.sh file.

Comment: Yep, the user who owns the application also runs teh capistrano deploy script. However it appears standard users cannot restart upstart daemons?

Comment: Does the user who owns the application have permission to start every process that your restart.sh script is trying to restart?

Comment: Well I guess my previously question needs answering then?

I've since moved to using GOD to maintain unicorn processes. As log as god launches them under the unprivledged user, the capistrano script can call the restart GOD command :)